# Facebook PHP-SDK doesn't handle the code/state parameters passed through $_GET?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, oauth-2.0

It looks like the authentication bit when Facebook is sending `code`, `state` parameters through $_GET is not covered in PHP-SDK.

```
if(!empty($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['state']))
{
    $response   = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' . http_build_query(array('client_id' => AY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'client_secret' => AY_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, 'redirect_uri' => AY_FACEBOOK_TAB_URL, 'code' => $_GET['code'])));

    // now check state and parse access token

    ay($response);
}
```

Did I overlook something? If not, then what is the reason for not including it?

---

Please note that I did not ask to provide an example as DMCS and Luc Franken did so far.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the state and code parameters are discussed on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ in the part about CSRF protection.

```
 <?php 

   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
   $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

   session_start();
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

 ?>
```

Comment: You asked if the reason for having `state` was documented.  Not only did I provide you a link to the documentation for you I also posted their code snippet with that information in it.

Comment: Apologies, started with the code directly because it was not very readable, got the clue now after 3 times reading.

Comment: @DMCS, no, I did never ask for `the reason for having state (not) documented.` I asked why this code logic is not included in PHP-SDK.

Comment: Probably an oversight, or got lost in a source control merge.  You can log it as a defect

Comment: Did you file a bug?  What's the #?

Answer (score -1):

```
$response   = file_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' . http_build_query(
        array(
            'client_id' => AY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 
            'client_secret' => AY_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, 
            'redirect_uri' => AY_FACEBOOK_TAB_URL, 
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        )
    )
);

// now check state and parse access token

ay($response);
```

That reads a bit better.

Now your question: It just works:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1&client_secret=2&redirect_uri=3&code=1234

With this testing code:

```
echo 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' . http_build_query(
        array(
            'client_id' => 1, 
            'client_secret' => 2, 
            'redirect_uri' => 3, 
            'code' => '1234'
        )

);
```

Try to put the url in a variable, that will make life easier when debugging.

If you don't get anything in the code= part you might have values in the $_GET['code'] variable which won't be accepted by http_build_query since that function urlencodes the array data.